# how to aunthenticate password when retrieve email over SSL from POP3 server-c#

Tags: c#, email, ssl

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using System.IO; 

// Add EAGetMail namespace
using EAGetMail;

namespace receiveemail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a folder named "inbox" under current directory
            // to save the email retrieved.
            string curpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string mailbox = String.Format("{0}\\inbox", curpath);

            // If the folder is not existed, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(mailbox))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mailbox);
            }

            MailServer oServer = new MailServer("imap@gmail.com", "sample@gmail.com", "password", ServerProtocol.Imap4);
            MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");

            // Enable SSL connection
            oServer.SSLConnection = true;

            // Set 995 SSL POP3 port
            oServer.Port = 995;

            try
            {
                oClient.Connect(oServer);
                MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
                for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
                {
                    MailInfo info = infos[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                        info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL);

                    // Receive email from POP3 server
                    Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

                    Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);

                    // Generate an email file name based on date time.
                    System.DateTime d = System.DateTime.Now;
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cur = new
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                    string sdate = d.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", cur);
                    string fileName = String.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}{3}.eml",
                        mailbox, sdate, d.Millisecond.ToString("d3"), i);

                    // Save email to local disk
                    oMail.SaveAs(fileName, true);

                    // Mark email as deleted from POP3 server.
                    oClient.Delete(info);
                }

                // Quit and pure emails marked as deleted from POP3 server.
                oClient.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
            }

        }
    }
    }
```

Okay, so this is my code to retrieve emails. I wanted help regarding how I could authenticate the password I'll be passing as a parameter in:
 MailServer oServer = new MailServer("imap@gmail.com", "sample@gmail.com", "password", ServerProtocol.Imap4).
Could someone help me out?

Comment: and...not working ? Your code is just like the sample here : https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=1

Comment: Yes, it's the same but it's not working.

Comment: If you activate two-step-verification in google, then your password is app-specific-password. If not, then your normal password. IMAP port is 993, not 995, according to this : https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en